# How to switch windows of an app directly in current workspace?

Tags: gnome

It is possible to switch windows of an app directly in current workspace?

The default keybinding on gnome setting is `Alt+F6`

I had try set dconf like this but not working:

```
org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only
org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only
```

---

Complete the question from comment area:

Does alt + tab not work? why use alt+f6?

1. ALT+TAB is switch between windows in gnome desktop.
2. The ALT+F6 is switch between the same application but different windows in this application.

For example, you have three windows: 1 is gedit and 2 are web browser. When you press alt+tab you will switch in this 3 windows. But when you in web browser. You press ALT+F6 will switch in the 2 web browser without workspace restricted.

The question is possible set alt+f6 like use  Super+` and  org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only set true?

Comment: ALT+TAB doesn't work?

Comment: ALT+TAB is switch between windows in gnome desktop. The ALT+F6 is switch between the same application but different windows in this application. For example you have three windows: 1 is gedit and 2 are web browser. When you press alt+tab you will switch in this 3 windows. But when you in web browser. You press ALT+F6 will switch in the 2 web browser without workspace  restricted.

Comment: Add your comment to your question: it clarifies the question.